# How is this question on quantifying the political effects of an insult unclear?

Tags: support, closed-questions

I'd like to know how [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/3430/can-the-possible-negative-effects-of-an-insult-to-supporters-and-or-opponents-be) is unclear and how it can be changed for clarity to be reopened.

I edited to show the true intent: can the possible negative political effects of an insult by a politician be quantified?

I have provided some research examples.

If necessary, I can add something by the opposition, so this doesn't look like an anti-Democratic hackjob.

The Valerie Jarrett picture was chosen simply because its the only insult for the day and because of its "us vs them" appearance.

Answer (score 2):

Well, for starters... Your question goes on and on about Valerie Jarret, and then ends with a question that has *nothing whatsoever to do with Valerie Jarret*. I gotta assume that you started out to write a question about Valerie Jarret and got sidetracked along the way, but it's not really clear how or where.

Ignoring that, the only question in your question (stated in both the title and the last sentence) is impossibly vague. Again, I must assume you had an actual problem to solve at one point (perhaps one related to Valerie Jarret in some way?) and just lost track of it while writing. So, lead with the problem statement.

Comment: Yes, as a side interest, I wanted to know if the men in the gag gift were in fact white males.  I saw someplace else that claimed that they are, so that's no unimportant; however, from the beginning, I'm preoccupied with possible negative effects of political insults.  I have tried to edit per your concerns.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Despite your latest edits, your question is still very hard to read.

One of the reasons why your post is hard to read is because your sentence structure is too complex.

---

The first sentence of your question is a good example.

> **Politicians**, such as in the way below chosen for its timeliness and more importantly because of the supposed "white male problem" of the Democratic party which is not meant to say one side is better or worse than the other since both provide a continual stream of this sort, often **insult** **individuals** or groups, who support or oppose the insulters' interests, publicly and privately.

I've bolded 3 words in your sentence.  Those words are the subject, verb, and object of the sentence.

There are **49** words between your subject and your verb.  By the time I got to *"insult individuals"*, I had already forgotten who or what was *insulting individuals*, and had to look back to find that it was *Politicians.*

int hat 49 word gap:

- You reference your example of an insult long before the reader actually reads the words "insult".
- You Justify your example as an example of the "white male problem" well before "white male problem" has any meaning to the reader
- You make a disclaimer about how you intend no bias

And you do all that before the reader can be expected to know what your sentence is actually about.

---

In my opinion, your sentence structure is too complex and therefore takes an unreasonable amount of effort to parse.

You should read your question **out loud** and think about whether or not it sounds clear to you, and then edit it, until you are satisfied with it's clarity.

Comment: Just saw this answer.  I think the message box only works 80% of the time.  Anyways, I've tried to edit according to your suggestions.  Thank you for your suggestions!